# jQuery to change global css property from within an iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have using colobox which is a jquery modal window to create a login/regiestration process through modal pages called in an iframe.  I am hoping to be able to switch the css from a link within the iframe.   I am trying to change the height of the modal window when switching between ajax pages within the iframe.  If I try something like this it does not work..

```
$(".link").click(function () {
  $('#a').css('height', '763px!important');
  });
```

Is this possible or should I go to sleep now?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$('#a, #b, #c').css('height', '763px!important');
```

http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/

There's also a [list of all available selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) on jquery website, checking it out might be useful.

**edit**
Regarding iframe issue, you can access parent window containing this iframe with `parent` variable. For example, this will redirect parent browser window to home google page: `parent.location.href='http://google.com'`.
I never tried this with jquery, but maybe something like `$(parent.document).find('#a')` will perform search in the parent document too.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.parent

Comment: Thanks, that is a much better way to write this.  I am going to edit my question as I realized that this is not the problem, I can not even make this work with just one selector.  The real problem is that I am trying to make this happen from within an iframe :-/

Comment: @zac I've changed 'parent' to 'parent.document'. Obviously, we don't look for document elements in Window object.

Comment: Aha... I just figured out something at the same time, I ended up using 'top.document'  Thanks for your help!

Comment: @zac Well, _window.top_ is pretty similar to _window.parent_, only it returns topmost parent: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.top

Answer (score 1):

Try using something similar to

```
<style name="changeStyle">
</style>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('style[name="changeStyle"]').html('#myChangedStyle{background:green;}');
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery('selector1,selector2,seleccto3....').SomeAction(); 
//separate sectors with comma

in your case

jQuery('#a,#b,#c').css('height', '763px!important');
```